# IIS HTTPS Host Headers

Tags: ssl, iis-7, https, certificate, host-headers

In IIS I need to map `www.example.com` and `example.com` to use a specific SSL certificate. I have tried using `appcmd` and editing `applicationHost.config` but I don't see how to tie each host-header to a specific certificate. If I add the bindings in the config file and then look in the UI, no certificate is applied to bindings.

The certificate is for `www.example.com` but has an alias for `example.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the question using [this post](http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=80). Basically adding an * to the beginning of the friendly name of the certificate will allow you to edit the host header for a HTTPS binding in IIS7 manager.